# how to not allow empty key in Guava Multimap?

Tags: guava, multimap

I have this kind of situation, where i have a multimap which i add in the end to Oracle DB, which converts empty string("") to null, is there a way i can guarantee in the code that multimap will not allow adding an empty key? (for example Multimap.put("", "some value"))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both the keys and values of Guava's MultiMap are @Nullable and it doesn't have out of the box functionality to add a validation. So I would just build a validation in the code that puts the values. Something like:

```
if (!key.isEmpty){
    multiMap.put(key, value);
} else {
    log("Could not add " +value) // or throw an exception or do something else
}
```

---

Updated: after OP clarified that above doesn't apply to his use case, because parsing is done through Spring.

You could look into using ForwardingMultiMap:

> A multimap which forwards all its method calls to another multimap. Subclasses should override one or more methods to modify the behavior of the backing multimap as desired per the decorator pattern.
>   default method warning: This class does not forward calls to default methods. Instead, it inherits their default implementations. When those implementations invoke methods, they invoke methods on the ForwardingMultimap.

https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMultimap.html

I have never used this class myself, but it sounds like you can use it to forward to a subclass of your own design. Then in that subclass you could build the validation into the `put` method.

Comment: that would have worked, if it wasn't parsed through spring =]

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I guess you can use a ForwardingMultiMap? Will update my answer, becuase it's too long for comment